# javascript model in nextjs returning bad request 400 on fetch

Tags: javascript, next.js

i'm building a web application, in my web application i'm trying to creating a record by sending the data to the api endpoint, but everytime i make the request it returns a 400 bad request. I run it the same request in insomnia and everything was fine, can anybody help me to figure it out why it always return a 400 bad request on front end?

there is the code:

```js
async createEvent() {
    const requestBody = {
        userId: this.#userId,
        eventName: this.#name,
        eventDate: this.#date
    }

    const createEventResponse = await fetch(`http://localhost:3001/event/create`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(requestBody)
    });

    const { message } = await createEventResponse.json();

    if (createEventResponse.status === 200) {
        return {
            flag: true,
            message
        }
    } else if (createEventResponse.status ==- 401) {
        return {
            flag: false,
            message
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to debug your backend. The fontend can only tell you what it received from the backend.

Comment: a 400 bad request it means that he cant even get to the backend

Comment: No, 400 bad request means, that the server returned 400 bad request ...

Comment: i already looked on backend, the backend didn't receive anything

Comment: The question might be dumb. But are you sure, you are accessing the correct backend? ...

Answer (score 0):

The error was that one of the fields in the requestBody was undefined.